# Issues with Android studio running from Ramdisk

Tags: ubuntu, android-emulator, android-studio, android-virtual-device, ramdisk

I am running Android studio 0.3.2 from tmpfs(Ubuntu 13.10) mounted on /media/ramdisk/. I mount them using 'sudo sh StartRamDisk.sh' i.e. the owner and group of my android studio files loaded onto ramdisk is 'root'.

When i run the AVD manager even after setting my 'ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/jaggib/' it start in '/root/.android/avd'.

But every time i start Android emulator, i get this:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'Nexus'
PANIC: Could not open: Nexus
```

How can i fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix this after i reset the 'ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/home/jaggib/'.